# Bitcoind walletnotify configure on Laravel does not work

Tags: laravel, json-rpc, bitcoind

I have successfully configured bitcoind and connected it from a Laravel application. My issue now is walletnotify does not get triggered when a new transaction comes on an internally generated address.

bitcoin.conf

```
maxconnections=12
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
test.rpcport=18332
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0 --testing purposes
keypool=10000
server=1
testnet=1
txindex=1
walletnotify=/usr/bin/curl http://127.0.0.1/notify/%s
```

I have also tried with:

```
walletnotify=curl http://127.0.0.1/notify/%s
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/notify', 'HomeController@notify');
```

The Controller:

```
public function notify($tx) {

        $txinfo = Bitcoind::getRawTransaction($tx, true);

        $txinfo = $txinfo->get();

        .....

    }
```

Notes:
Blockchain is synced.
I have checked the debug.log from bitcoin but no errors from walletnotify or at least the curl when it should run.

If I manually call the route and pass a txid, everything goes well.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

WalletNotify config below works just fine.

```
walletnotify=curl http://127.0.0.1/notify/%s
```

The problem was I build the function that verifies the transaction in the HomeController, which is guarded by the AUTH middleware. As I started this for testing purposes, I forget about the guard from the HomeController which is created by laravel authentication scaffolding.